# Getting Error when converting json object to class type array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I am getting json object from service, i wanted to iterate to this json object and fill array of class type.
Following is the code to call the service

```
 public GetMapData(): Observable<Response> {
    var path = 'http://my.blog.net/blog.php?type=trendingDestiny';



    return this.http.get(path)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });

}
self.blogapi.GetMapData().subscribe(
        x => {
            this.MapData = x;
            console.log("MapData", this.MapData);
        });
```

Following is the json response

```
[
{
    "post_id": 77,
    "post_title": "Delhi",
    "post_content": "DelhiDelhiDelhi",
    "post_date": "2017-07-24 11:47:08",
    "imageurl": false,
    "cat_name": [
        {
            "term_id": 7,
            "name": "FOODIE",
            "slug": "foodie",               
            "category_parent": 0
        }
    ],
    "longitude": "75.857849",
    "latitude": "33.888586",
    "region_name": "Asia"
},
{
    "post_id": 75,
    "post_title": "Goa",
    "post_content": "this is goa",
    "post_date": "2017-07-24 11:03:59",
    "imageurl": false,
    "cat_name": [
        {
            "term_id": 7,
            "name": "FOODIE",
            "slug": "foodie",               
            "category_parent": 0
        }
    ],
    "longitude": "75.857849",
    "latitude": "33.888586",
    "region_name": "Asia"
}]
```

Following is the typescript code

```
this.MapData.forEach(map => {
        this.Mapdatalist.push({
            postid: map.post_id,
            regionname: map.region_name,
            longitude: map.longitude

        });
    });
```

or i also tried

```
for (let data of this.MapData)
    {
        console.log("error",data);

    }
```

But nothing works. It gives me error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Please help what is going wrong.

Comment: `this.MapData` is undefined.

Comment: How are you getting this json object from the service? What does that code look like?

Comment: @Shubham this.mapdata has the data when i use ngfor in html it works.

Comment: this.mapdata or this.MapData ?

Comment: @C.jacking try to log `this.MapData` in console and check what you are getting.

Comment: @DeborahK    return this.http.get(path)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            });

Comment: it's this.MapData @Shubham

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the code there? It does not format very nicely in the comment section. And could you add the code that calls the service?

Comment: @Shubham yes i am getting in console Array(1)
0:Object
cat_name:Array(1)
imageurl:false
latitude:"33.888586"
longitude:"75.857849"
post_content:"DelhiDelhiDelhi"
post_date:"2017-07-24 11:47:08"
post_id:77
post_title:"Delhi"
region_name:"Asia"

Comment: @DeborahK i have added that code in question.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to iterate the response?

Comment: @AJT_82 i wanted to create another json from the json response of service so that i can push that new json in amchart map.

Comment: Yes I understand, but **where** are you trying to do it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array= [
{
    "post_id": 77,
    "post_title": "Delhi",
    "post_content": "DelhiDelhiDelhi",
    "post_date": "2017-07-24 11:47:08",
    "imageurl": false,
    "cat_name": [
        {
            "term_id": 7,
            "name": "FOODIE",
            "slug": "foodie",               
            "category_parent": 0
        }
    ],
    "longitude": "75.857849",
    "latitude": "33.888586",
    "region_name": "Asia"
},
{
    "post_id": 75,
    "post_title": "Goa",
    "post_content": "this is goa",
    "post_date": "2017-07-24 11:03:59",
    "imageurl": false,
    "cat_name": [
        {
            "term_id": 7,
            "name": "FOODIE",
            "slug": "foodie",               
            "category_parent": 0
        }
    ],
    "longitude": "75.857849",
    "latitude": "33.888586",
    "region_name": "Asia"
}];
//console.log(array);
var mapdata = [];
$.each(array,function(i,v){
 mapdata.push({"postid":v.post_id,"regionname":v.region_name,"longitude":v.longitude});
})
console.log(mapdata);
```

Comment: @ C.jacking please use jquery library for $.each function

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you assigned response to "this.MapData". I have created same scenario, where it is working. It might be case that "this.MapData" is not declared and defined correctly.

Comment: i have also did the same as yours, i can also see the this.MapData in console but still it is giving me udefined error.

Comment: can i further create this array into json?